# Attempting to create new state, but property is resolving to 2

Tags: react-redux

I'm new to react and redux, and I'm attempting to create new state, but it appears that I'm not updating the state properly.

here's the code inside my case:

```
  case SUBMIT_NOTE:
    console.log(payload.note);
    return{ ...state, notes: state.notes.push(payload.note)};
```

`payload.note` resolves to the object I want to push into the array, but in redux-logger it shows as `state.notes = 2`

Not sure how this happened. I'm new to the spread operator, and pure functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `.push()` mutates in some way, or simply returns the number of indexes in the array, and can't be used for state operations. `.concat(note)` worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
const initial_state = {
    notes: []
}
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SUBMIT_NOTE:
            console.log(payload.note);
            return {
                ...state,
                notes: payload.note
            }
    }
}
```

We never mutate the state in redux. You can return the new state by just assigning the new value to the object.

Hope this help's you!

Comment: that would be more helpful if I were replacing the notes field on the state, but I'm adding a note object to the array. Thanks anyway!